# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound no work in iphone5

Tags: ios, audio

```
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
 ....
 @property (assign,nonatomic)SystemSoundID soundId;
 ...
 -(IBAction)testSound:(id)sender {
     if (_soundId == 0 ) {
         NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound"    ofType:@"wav"];
         NSURL *soundUrl= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
         AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundUrl, &_soundID);
     }
     AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
 }
```

same code above  runs well for iphone6 plus,for simulator (iphone5,..) but not work for iphone 5 device ,can anyone say why? 
thanks

Comment: Any error? what are the iOS version respectively? Did you clean & rebuild?

Comment: no error .. ios version:8.3 for device (iphone6 plus,iphone5)

Comment: Even Xcode console is empty ? Oops

Comment: No error,so no content in console of Xcode.And when I NSLog _soundId ,it prints 4097,that is to say,_soundId has value,not empty. And I use AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate),the iphone5 can vibrate without sound